# Differences between value and safe_value

Tags: 7, entities, security

What are the differences between `['value']` and `['safe_value']`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a value, passed through the function [`_text_sanitize()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--text--text.module/function/_text_sanitize/7). You can read more in the official docs.

If you are using `'safe_value'`, you may be also interested in this article: [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).

Answer (score 16):

The main difference it that the safe_value is passed through the function [_text_sanitize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--text--text.module/function/_text_sanitize/7).

Comment: At the same time :)

Comment: Depending on the type of value you want in `safe_value`, you can forego the use of `_text_sanitize()` and use `check_plain($text)` for plain text or `check_markup($text, $format)` for HTML

Answer (score 1):

For Readers benefit, DO NOT use safe_value data when making SQL statements. In other words, strings containing ampersand ( & ) will become ( `&amp;` ) fail to get the expected results.