# convert &#039; to html character

Tags: 7

I have this code:

```
$items[$k]->user->nome = $accounts[$item->uid]->field_nome['und'][0]['safe_value']." ".$accounts[$item->uid]->field_cognome['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

And the output is this:

```
L&#039;itto Giovanni
```

But I want (in HTML)

```
L'itto Giovanni
```

in html head I have

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 3):

"safe_value" is a "value", passed through the function _text_sanitize().

You can use php function [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) or use "value" instant of "safe_value". [Differences between value and safe_value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/differences-between-value-and-safe-value)