# Do I have to set a 'safe_value' with each textarea's field value when I set it programmatically?

Tags: entities

Do I have to provide both 'value' & 'safe_value'?

Comment: Enough: $wrapper->body->set(array('value' => "<b>The second body.</b>"));

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you try setting just `value` and see what happens? If you have specific doubts, you should ask about them.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you are adding field programmatically you only need to set `value`.

The `safe value` is generated when the field is loaded.
It is the *value* passed through the function `_text_sanitize()` which in this case i think is called through `text_field_load()`

More information on the difference between them here :

[Differences between value and safe_value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/differences-between-value-and-safe-value)